# C requires that a struct or union has at least one member

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm getting a bunch of weird errors from the compiler when I try to compile this code.

I'm just trying to write a basic linked list, and the header file compiles fine when run on its own but when I compile the c file everything falls apart

linkedlist.h

```
typedef struct Data
{
    char *title;
} Data;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    LinkedList *next;
    Data *data;
} LinkedList;

LinkedList *createnew(void);
void destroylist(LinkedList *old);
Data *adddata(void);
void destroydata(Data *old);
```

LinkedList.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"

LinkedList *createnew(void) {
    LinkedList *newnode = (LinkedList *) malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    newnode->data = adddata();
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

void destroylist(LinkedList *old) {
    destroydata(old->data);
    free(old);
    return;
}

Data *adddata(void) {
    Data *newdata = (Data *) malloc(sizeof(Data));
    newdata->title = NULL;
    return newdata;
}

void destroydata(Data *old) {
    free(old->title);
    free(old);
    return;
}
```

and finally what the compiler spits out

```
linkedlist.h(8): error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member
linkedlist.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LinkedList'
linkedlist.h(10): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
linkedlist.h(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
linkedlist.h(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
linkedlist.h(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
linkedlist.h(13): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
linkedlist.c(4): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
linkedlist.c(5): error C2065: 'LinkedList' : undeclared identifier
linkedlist.c(5): error C2065: 'newnode' : undeclared identifier
linkedlist.c(5): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
linkedlist.c(6): error C2065: 'newnode' : undeclared identifier
linkedlist.c(6): error C2223: left of '->data' must point to struct/union
linkedlist.c(7): error C2065: 'newnode' : undeclared identifier
linkedlist.c(7): error C2223: left of '->next' must point to struct/union
linkedlist.c(8): error C2065: 'newnode' : undeclared identifier
linkedlist.c(8): warning C4047: 'return' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
linkedlist.c(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
linkedlist.c(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
linkedlist.c(11): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
linkedlist.c(11): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'old'
```

I'm confused because it looks like it finds both files but then it has trouble with the header even though it works fine alone.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is strange, but

```
typedef struct LinkedList
{
    LinkedList *next;
    Data *data;
} LinkedList;
```

`LinkedList` is not a known type in the definition, it is only known after the definition is complete, it must be

```
typedef struct LinkedList
{
    struct LinkedList *next;
    Data *data;
} LinkedList;
```

Answer (score 4):

Header files aren't compiled on their own. Their only use is being `#include`d elsewhere.

The error in your header is this part:

```
typedef struct LinkedList  // <- defines the type 'struct LinkedList'
{
    LinkedList *next;      // <- attempts to use the type 'LinkedList', which isn't defined at this point
} LinkedList;              // <- defines the type 'LinkedList', or it would if the previous code were correct
```

There are a few possible ways to fix this:

```
// forget about 'LinkedList'; just use 'struct LinkedList' everywhere
struct LinkedList {
    struct LinkedList *next;
};
```

```
// use 'struct LinkedList' in its own definition but provide typedef to users
struct LinkedList {
    struct LinkedList *next;
};
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
```

```
// like the previous version, but combine struct + typedef
typedef struct LinkedList {
    struct LinkedList *next;
} LinkedList;
```

And my favorite:

```
// establish alias first, then use it everywhere
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
struct LinkedList {
    LinkedList *next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is cleaner than alternate suggestions (**edit**: I see that melpomene mentioned this before me):

```
typedef struct Data Data;
struct Data
{
    char *title;
};

typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
struct LinkedList
{
    LinkedList *next;
    Data *data;
};
```

You will find if/when you move on to C++ that you can just remove the typedef lines.

If you have mutually referring structs, move all the typedefs up to the top, e.g.,

```
typedef Type1 Type1;
typedef Type2 Type2;

struct Type1
{
    Type2* link;
};

struct Type2
{
    Type1* link;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding `struct` before `LinkedList`, you might need to explicitly set the "compile as" option to c++ in Visual Studio.

I had struggled with this C2016 error for a while and it finally been fixed by setting the option.